# What is the difference between high altitude vs low altitude approach?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, approach

Is there any factor that influences the decision of whether to take a high or low instrument  approach (e.g. Hi Tacan or Low Tacan)?

What are the differences between these two approaches?

Comment: I was told, last century, the choice between Hi and Low was dependent on the theater.  That is, the Hi approach was used (or practiced) for areas that may contain hostile aircraft.